# Google Lens-like zoomable and selectable Flutter widget

Tags: flutter, text-recognition

I'm building a Google Lens clone app. In Google Lens, you can take a picture and get the text from it. The app marks the text found by using some overlays (in the picture below). That overlay can be zoomed along with the image, and even selectable. I wonder if Flutter have any widget similar to that or if there are any way to implement that feature.

Google Lens app feature:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxCEg.jpg)

I'm new to Flutter, sorry for bad grammar.

Here is my code so far. I'm using `google_mlkit_text_recognition` package to analyze the image.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_text_recognition/google_mlkit_text_recognition.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as dev;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image Picker Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Image Picker Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, this.title});

  final String? title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<XFile>? _mediaFileList;
  RecognizedText? _recognizedText;
  final textRecognizer = TextRecognizer();

  final maxWidth = 393.7272727272727;
  Size _imageSize = const Size(0, 0);
  double _scale = 1.0;
  String text = "";
  final ValueNotifier<bool> _isSelecting = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

  Future<Size> _getImageResolution(XFile imageFile) {
    final File file = File(imageFile.path);
    final img = Image.file(file);
    final ImageStream stream = img.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration.empty);
    final Completer<Size> completer = Completer<Size>();

    stream.addListener(
        ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool synchronousCall) {
      completer.complete(Size(
        info.image.width.toDouble(),
        info.image.height.toDouble(),
      ));
    }));

    return completer.future;
  }

  void _setImageFileListFromFile(XFile? value) async {
    _mediaFileList = value == null ? null : <XFile>[value];
    if (_mediaFileList != null) {
      final image = _mediaFileList![0];
      final size = await _getImageResolution(image);
      setState(() {
        _imageSize = size;
        _scale = maxWidth / size.width;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<RecognizedText> _processImage(XFile? pickedFile) async {
    final image = pickedFile == null ? null : File(pickedFile.path);
    final inputImage = InputImage.fromFile(image!);
    final recognizedText = await textRecognizer.processImage(inputImage);
    for (TextBlock block in recognizedText.blocks) {
      final Rect rect = block.boundingBox;
      final String text = block.text;
      final List<Point<int>> cornerPoints = block.cornerPoints;
      dev.log("rect: $rect");
      dev.log("text: $text");
      dev.log("cornerPoints: $cornerPoints");
    }

    return recognizedText;
  }

  dynamic _pickImageError;

  String? _retrieveDataError;

  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> _onImageButtonPressed(
    ImageSource source, {
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    if (context.mounted) {
      try {
        final XFile? pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(
          source: source,
        );
        final text = await _processImage(pickedFile);
        setState(() {
          _setImageFileListFromFile(pickedFile);
          _recognizedText = text;
        });
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          _pickImageError = e;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _isSelecting.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _previewImages() {
    final Text? retrieveError = _getRetrieveErrorWidget();
    if (retrieveError != null) {
      return retrieveError;
    }
    if (_mediaFileList != null) {
      return Semantics(
        label: 'image_picker_example_picked_images',
        child: ListView.builder(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Semantics(
                label: 'image_picker_example_picked_image',
                child: SelectionArea(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Stack(children: [
                        kIsWeb
                            ? Image.network(_mediaFileList![index].path)
                            : Image.file(
                                File(_mediaFileList![index].path),
                                errorBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                    Object error, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                                  return const Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                          'This image type is not supported'));
                                },
                              ),
                        CustomPaint(
                          painter: TextBlocksPainter(
                              _recognizedText!.blocks, _scale),
                        ),
                      ]),
                      Text(
                        _recognizedText!.text,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
          },
          itemCount: _mediaFileList!.length,
        ),
      );
    } else if (_pickImageError != null) {
      return Text(
        'Pick image error: $_pickImageError',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    } else {
      return const Text(
        'You have not yet picked an image.',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _handlePreview() {
    return _previewImages();
  }

  Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
    final LostDataResponse response = await _picker.retrieveLostData();
    if (response.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    if (response.file != null) {
      setState(() {
        if (response.files == null) {
          _setImageFileListFromFile(response.file);
        } else {
          _mediaFileList = response.files;
        }
      });
    } else {
      _retrieveDataError = response.exception!.code;
    }
  }

  void _onPointerDown(PointerDownEvent event) {
    _isSelecting.value = true;
    for (var block in _recognizedText!.blocks) {
      final String text = block.text;
      final List<Point<int>> cornerPoints = block.cornerPoints;

      // Create a Path from the corner points
      final path = Path()
        ..moveTo(cornerPoints.first.x.toDouble() * _scale,
            cornerPoints.first.y.toDouble() * _scale);
      for (var i = 1; i < cornerPoints.length; i++) {
        path.lineTo(cornerPoints[i].x.toDouble() * _scale,
            cornerPoints[i].y.toDouble() * _scale);
      }
      path.close();

      // Check if the event position is within the polygon
      if (path.contains(Offset(
          event.position.dx,
          event.position.dy -
              kToolbarHeight -
              MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top))) {
        dev.log("Position is inside the polygon.");
        dev.log("Text: $text");
        // setState(() {
        //   this.text = text;
        // });
      }
    }
  }

  void _onPointerMove(PointerMoveEvent event) {}

  void _onPointerUp(PointerUpEvent event) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title!),
      ),
      body: Listener(
        onPointerDown: _onPointerDown,
        onPointerMove: _onPointerMove,
        onPointerUp: _onPointerUp,
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Center(
            child: !kIsWeb && defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
                ? FutureBuilder<void>(
                    future: retrieveLostData(),
                    builder:
                        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.none:
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return const Text(
                            'You have not yet picked an image.',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          );
                        case ConnectionState.done:
                          return _handlePreview();
                        case ConnectionState.active:
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text(
                              'Pick image/video error: ${snapshot.error}}',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            );
                          } else {
                            return const Text(
                              'You have not yet picked an image.',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            );
                          }
                      }
                    },
                  )
                : _handlePreview(),
          );
        }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Semantics(
            label: 'image_picker_example_from_gallery',
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource.gallery, context: context);
              },
              heroTag: 'image0',
              tooltip: 'Pick Image from gallery',
              child: const Icon(Icons.photo),
            ),
          ),
          if (_picker.supportsImageSource(ImageSource.camera))
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource.camera, context: context);
                },
                heroTag: 'image2',
                tooltip: 'Take a Photo',
                child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Text? _getRetrieveErrorWidget() {
    if (_retrieveDataError != null) {
      final Text result = Text(_retrieveDataError!);
      _retrieveDataError = null;
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

typedef OnPickImageCallback = void Function(
    double? maxWidth, double? maxHeight, int? quality);

class TextBlocksPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<TextBlock> textBlocks;
  final double scale;

  TextBlocksPainter(this.textBlocks, this.scale);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

    for (var block in textBlocks) {
      for (var line in block.lines) {
        for (var element in line.elements) {
          final path = Path()
            ..moveTo(element.cornerPoints[0].x.toDouble() * scale,
                element.cornerPoints[0].y.toDouble() * scale);

          for (var i = 1; i < element.cornerPoints.length; i++) {
            path.lineTo(element.cornerPoints[i].x.toDouble() * scale,
                element.cornerPoints[i].y.toDouble() * scale);
          }
          path.close();

          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: "I wonder if Flutter have any widget similar to that or if there are any way to implement that feature." check `InteractiveViewer`